# Are there general accuracy requirements for aircraft power supplies?

Tags: aircraft-systems, avionics, aircraft-certification

Let's say I have some LRU device that requires some DC voltage to be powered on. Are there any general requirements in aviation/aerospace that say how accurate that supply voltage must be in order to be allowed on a plane?

Update:

To be more specific, consider an LRU that takes 28V on the input and provides it to a DC-DC converter. I would like to know how accurate that 28V being provided, needs to be.

Comment: For the updated question, the LRU (if it's a cots equipment) probably has established specs for its input power. 704E/F etc. so the spec data sheet should contain the info. If not, it's kind of a tricky subject. Are you trying to develop a  power distribution system? It would help receive even more practical answers.

Comment: @GürkanÇetin Thanks, that's a good bit of information for when dealing with a specific LRU. Also, no I am not trying to develop a power distribution system. I am just asking a general question here as to whether or not there is a global set of requirements for input power that applies to all LRUs (outside of the spec data sheet for a particular LRU).

Comment: Sorry for noob question, but could you define "LRU" ? Are you talking about [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-replaceable_unit) ? If so, what type of equipement can that be ? That's unclear to me.

Comment: @kebs No problem, I'd be happy to help. As you suggested, an LRU is a line-replaceable unit and that's exactly what I am talking about in this question. Line replaceable units are parts or modules of an aircraft, things like fuel gauges or inertial measurement devices that contribute to operating the aircraft.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Short answer:

- Operational voltages on the 28 V bus may range from 22 V to 30 V.
- Abnormal voltages on the 28 V bus may occur from 0 V to 60 V.

The detailed requirements depend on the manufacturer, the type of plane and the jurisdiction.

### USA: MIL-STD-704

US military standard [MIL-STD-704(F) *Aircraft Electrical Power Characteristics*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIL-STD-704) defines electrical properties of military aircraft equipment. For instance the 28 V DC bus is specified as:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

A similar standard should exist for commercial aircraft, unless they just apply MIL-STD-704 as well.

### Europe: ISO 1540

In Europe there is [ISO 1540:2006 *Aerospace -- Characteristics of aircraft electrical systems*](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=42067). This standard differentiates by the actual power source:

- Category A: TRU (transformer)
- Category B: engine driven DC generator
- Category R: regulated DC power from active converter

Category A and B are specified identically for their DC characteristics. Category B is the worst case for AC ripples. Category R is the best case, as it is already regulated. Nevertheless, connected equipment needs to cope with the worst case, that is category B (engine driven generator).

ISO 1540 specifies the 28 V DC bus characteristics (summarized) as:

- 28 V DC bus - Normal operation: 22 V - 30 V
- 28 V DC bus - abnormal/onset: 0 V - 60 V

[image]

[image]

Comment: Very nice summary. Discusses the power supply inputs *to* the LRUs present on the voltage bus exactly like I was asking for. Thank you very much.

Comment: Cat-Z can go upto 80V for 100ms

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on whether you are connecting directly to the main DC bus (28V presumably) or being powered by a DC/DC converter.

DC/DC converters are required to meet [TSO C71 Airborne Static ("DC to DC") Electrical Power Converter](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgTSO.nsf/0/30028A6E1E82905B86256DC1005A3FF2?OpenDocument) in a certified installation.

Many LRUs I have seen are designed to operate on a DC input voltage from 10 VDC - 32 VDC

If the main power bus is AC, you would need to have an AC to DC converter to provide the DC power.

If you are trying to test the LRU, it should have a specified input voltage range.

Comment: That document you posted refers to the output of the DC-DC. I want to know about the *input* power supply voltage *to* the LRU. Maybe I should have been more specific.

Comment: For example, if the DC-DC on the LRU takes in 28V... I want to know*how accurate* does that 28V have to be?

Comment: Your LRU should probably accept anything from 10 VDC to 32 VDC as an input unless are being powered by a converter that will provide you with 28 VDC. That converter would need to meet TSO C71 for its output power (which is your input)

Comment: I think there is a lot of useful information here but no DC-DC at the LRU input, it's just an LRU being tested with a bench-top power supply. So that's why I am asking about the voltage that goes into the LRU.

Comment: So you are testing an LRU - are you trying to just verify it is functional or are you trying to verify the full range of input voltage for the LRU?

Comment: I am not asking about a specific LRU here, but more about the voltage line that any LRU present on the plane must utilize for power and what that voltage line's tolerances are to be acceptable to the LRU.

Comment: An LRU could be connected to a variety of power busses and different LRUs are going to operate on a different input range depending on its use. The electrical power system is going to be different from aircraft to aircraft based on the OEM design requirements, starter/generator vs alternator, batteries, APU, etc. There isn't any FAA regulation as to what voltage range or tolerances every plane must meet because every plane can be different.